# Regex Get Value before string or number

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to ask is that possible to get digit or string after The word.
e.g

```
Abc ddd 1 0.4 44 USD 99 00 99
cc gg 1 0.4 445 66 USD 100 00 999
bb dd xx cc 56 78 99 65 35.45 USD 99 00 88 66 99
```

Out put target any value before USD

```
44
66
35.45
```

meaning that any value before USD.

Try using below code but couldnt get

```
(?<=USD\s\d+)\S+
```

Comment: Jam, did the solution below help?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex attempts to match one or more non-whitespace chars that are *immediately preceded* with `USD` + a whitespace + one or more digits. However, you need to get the numbers *that are to the left* of the `USD` substring.

You can use a lookahead based solution here:

```js
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s+USD\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E6teeb/1).

*Details*:

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `(?=\s+USD\b)` - the positive lookahead makes sure there are

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
  - `USD\b` - and an `USD` substring as a whole word (as `\b` is a word boundary).